# Where should I store my database username and password in a PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords

This is probably true for other languages as well. I've created several websites by now, many of which use databases (usually mySQL). I need to store the database password somewhere in the sourcecode, but this seems like a security problem, and a a bit like a hack. Is there a better way to store the password, apart from a config file which is included everywhere I need to use the database?

**Duplicate: [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)**

Answer (score 1):

a config file that isn´t reachable from outside, sotre ist somewhere exept of htdocs etc.