# how to store mysql password in a seperated file?

Tags: database, file, passwords

how can i add my database password in a seperate file for my website instead of writing them in my source code like this:

```
$this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","samplepassword");
$db_select = mysql_select_db("mydb",$this->connection);
```

to make it secure but i don't know how to mention them in my file:

this is seperated file:

```
<files mypasswdfile>
order allow,deny
</files>
```

where to put passwords and how should be the syntax?

Comment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to store database login credentials for a PHP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882882/where-to-store-database-login-credentials-for-a-php-application)

Comment: plz any help is appreciated