# Can I place PHP config files securely in a publicly accessible folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

GoDaddy does not a give FTP root access to my account, meaning I can only access the `public_html` folder and not the `includes` folder.

Is there any way I can include the config files in that public folder but somehow make it so  only the server can access them in a secure way? How does Wordpress do it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

Comment: If you read the top answers for that question, you will find that they provide solutions for securing your config files when you need to store them in your public web folder.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `.htaccess` file to restrict Website Access.
Take a look of [this article](http://its.virginia.edu/websupport/htaccess.html).

Answer (score 1):

just make sure they have a `.php` extension.
(and actually contain PHP code of course)

Comment: I think they mean the php.ini that GoDaddy lets you have in the root of your account (to force php settings).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress keeps the config file in the main folder. Just make sure you have a .php extension and you dont echo anything from that. (I know you wont.)

People really cant get the details inside your php file unless you echo something, or the chmod of the file is set wrong so that people may be able to actually download the file.

As xdazz said, you can also restrict access to your config files, but I think its just for MORE protection, and you are still safe without that.