# Secure way to connect to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adminstrating a website for a very small group of people (50-60). The website has a simple login and all user data is stored in a MySQL database and the site is hosted by a well renowned webhotel.

The way I now connect to the database is through a single user account, specified in the database with the right to read and change, to make sure each user can alter their own password. The script (mysql_conn.php) is included in the needed pages and looks like this:

```
$server = "server_name";
$username_sql = "user@servername"; // This format is specific for that webhotel
$password_sql = "A_strong_password";    // Hard coded in the file

$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username_sql, $password_sql);
$db = mysql_select_db("user_list", $conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES Utf8");
if(!$db) {
    echo "Error message";
exit();
}
```

Technically it works like a charm, but I'm not sure this is the best way to go, especially with the password. Also, should I include some sort of database disconnection at the end of each page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd outsorce the login-data into a file called something like "dbConnection.inc.php" and store it in a directory not accessible from outside.

In extreme cases it could happen that your provider serves .php pages as plain text. If that happens visitors could see your password. But if it's outsorced you'd prevent that...

Answer (score 3):

First of all using mysql_* is not recommend for new code, see [PHP Introduction ot MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)
Consider switching to PDO instead if possible.

Second of all, storing password in PHP is pretty safe and even safer than saving it in plain text like xml or ini etc. Unless your web server have malfunction and unable to serve PHP pages, running your PHP script directly (or accessing it via web browser) will never expose the password (as opposed to xml/ini file).

Consider storing the password in some config.php that is NOT accessible from web browser (i.e. somewhere above the public root).

The only scenario that is possible to hijack your password is when your web server is hacked, but in that case not matter how you save the password (unless its encrypted) it will be hijacked.

A note if you decide to switch to PDO, PDO if fails to connect, throws [PDOException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) which in case if php configured to show errors WILL DISCLOSE YOUR PASSWORD. See [The related bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34628). So use it with caution!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks. I've now stored the sensitive data in a config-file one step up and it works fine.