# Which would be the best way of encryption for following scenario?

Tags: java, encryption

I want to know which would be the best java encryption type I can use to secure my application authentication details. 
In my application I have to use credentials for database and one application. I am putting it in one properties file.

```
db_username = abc
db_password = password
```

If I dont want my password to be visible in properties file. But I cant hardcode it in my application. Its a command prompt application and run using script which runs it automatically. What are the available encryption methods I can use?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You could take the username and password as arguments to your program, which you would call like this for example:

```
java -jar yourProgram -user john -pass 1234
```

You then move the security issue to the OS (make sure your batch is only accessible by authorised users).

Alternatively you can pass a properties file, which you place is a secure location.

See also [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually I can not go with this option as end user will not agree on it. I will have to do it with the same approach.. Still trying to give them few option out of which they may accept any one..

Comment: In the end if you just encrypt the file, you will need to decrypt it and someone smart enough will be able to do the same.