# Any benefit of putting MySQL code and PHP code in different files?

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder what are benefits of separating MySQL code from PHP code.

Currently our MySQL code is not separated and we're still evaluating if this is a good thing to do, what are pros / cons, if any or is it the same?

Below is a simple example to help you understand what I mean.

PHP script (log.php):

```
require_once '../dbconnect.php';
require_once '../classes/database/db_log.php';

$dbActivitylog = new db_tblactivitylog;

$distinct_users = $dbActivitylog->distinct_users();

foreach($distinct_users as $user)
{
  echo '<span class="fancy_color">{$user}</span><br />";
}
```

MySQL code => db_log.php:

```
class db_tblactivitylog
{
    // Return an array of distinct users in the activity log
    public  function    distinct_users()
    {
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT user FROM log ORDER BY user ASC";
        $result = full_query($query);
        $distinct_users = array();
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $distinct_users[] = $data['user'];
        }
        return $distinct_users;
    }

    // This function deletes $max_rows_to_delete rows in excess of the activitylimit in config, that match the where condition, keeping the newest rows
    public  function    truncate_rows($where, $max_rows_to_delete=9999)
    {
        global  $CONFIG;

        $max_rows_to_keep = $CONFIG['ActivityLimit'];
        $result = select_query( "log", "", $where, "id", "DESC", $max_rows_to_keep.",".$max_rows_to_delete);
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
                    // delete query function, nothing unusual
            delete_query( "log", array( "id" => $data['id'] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

**We are planning to use MySQLi, just wonder if there are any direct benefits of separating code as we can do it on the way?**

Comment: Do whatever makes your code easier to manage and maintain

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direct benefit of putting database parameters in a separate file is that by doing it you are able to put them in a place where they are not publicly accessible - like above your DocumentRoot folder. By doing that you are greatly increasing the security of your database access.

Comment: Hm...not entirely sure I see how that makes sense. Any strings written in a PHP file (`$defaultUsername = "Mingebag";`) have just as much risk of being output to the client as files read from another folder into a variable - which is to say none if the code is written as intended. Maybe I'm missing something though...?

Comment: If the file is outside of publicly accessible place it prevents attackers from using direct access exploits like manipulating server handlers (i.e. making Apache believe that a `.php` file is a plain text file, thus outputting it). Furthermore putting it in a separate folder allows for setting a more restrictive set of permissions on a file-system level.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I guess the biggest vulnerabilities of the sites I write in the future will be my lack of hacking imagination.

Answer (score 0):

- by using `db_connect` in a separate file, it becomes inaccessible to
  general users and this way, provides better security to login credentials and other sensitive data.....read here
  for clearing out your query
  [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)
- also, speaking of security, your are using  `mysql_` which offers
  `sql_injection` risk and is depreciated....use either `mysqli` or `PDO` for better security!

hope this helps!!