# How to extract only numeric value from "xyz123" string then add 5 in first numeric i.e. 1 and then print xyz623 in final output

Tags: php, arrays

How to extract only numeric value from "xyz123" string then add 5 in first numeric i.e. 1 and then print xyz623 in final output.

```
if(isset($login)){
    $length = strlen($pass);
    $c = false;
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
        if(preg_match('/^[0-9]$/',$pass[$i]) && $c==false){
            $a = (int)$pass[$i];
            $b = $a + 5;
            echo "<br>".$b."<br>";
            $c = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What should happen if the first numeric character is 8?

Comment: What would happen if `$b >= 10`?

Comment: The "password-encryption" tag worries me...

Comment: Logic 101: Are all homework problems [toy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_problem)?

Comment: If character is 8 then value for $b is 13.

Comment: Before this was edited, it was tagged `password-encryption`. Please, please don't use this as any kind of password encryption scheme. PHP has great [password hashing and management built in.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: To encrypt password using algorithm is my last step but firstly I want to do add some logic to password then I will encrypt. I am beginner but I am trying to add some logic b before using any encryption.

Comment: @VijayPatial Increment a number inside someone's password doesn't sound logical.. and very very far from encryption.

Comment: If we strictly assign password with charcter, special symbol and numeric value then we can add number during registration page and subtract during login. But I don't know is this possible during login if we use decrypt password.

Comment: @VijayPatial How is that helpful? If I type in xyz123 you're going to mangle that with your 'decryption' before sending it to the database where its stored as zyx623? What are you really trying to accomplish? You don't want to store passwords in a db?

Comment: Look @Mike my logic is I have a password field in registration form, if user enter password then we going to check password must contain characters, number and special symbol. secondly we check string with first numeric number in any index of array and we add 5 to that numeric value and we leave next numeric value as it is in a string. third we encrypt the new modified string and fourth stored to database.

Comment: "secondly we check string with first numeric number in any index of array and we add 5 to that numeric value and we leave next numeric value as it is in a string" - I'll repeat myself, why is that helpful? You're checking minimum requirements for passwords.. good. You're encrypting passwords in the db.. good. Why do you need to find an integer in the middle of the password and add 5??

Comment: To make password more secure isn't it?

Comment: @VijayPatial You just had 4 different people here tell you that doesn't make the password more secure.

Comment: @Mike what you suggest what is good if we want to more secure password?

Comment: @VijayPatial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

Comment: Please explain how xyz623 is any more secure than xyz123.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried my best to get an answer to that.

Comment: @Mike Encryption and Decryption is good if we add some extra logic in it then what's the deal?

Comment: @VijayPatial You said "third we encrypt the new modified string and fourth stored to database. " No, no no. Do this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: That's not extra logic, that's BS.

Comment: @PeteR if this is BS then why you don't share you knowledge?

Comment: Because you'd probably just add 5 to it.

Comment: @PeteR What you did during registration page if password need to store in database?

Comment: @VijayPatial: I use this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$str = 'xyz123';

$output = preg_replace_callback('/([a-z]+)(\d{1})/i', function($m) {
    $added = $m[2] + 5;    // adding 5 to the number
    return $m[1] . $added; // return the concatenated string
}, $str);

echo $output; // => xyz623
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/84449)