# Avoid hardcoded Credentials mysqli php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am developing a simple php application which needs connecting to Database
This is part of the code that creates connection to db

```
private $mysqli;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->mysqli = new \mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "mydb");
}
```

My question: how to avoid hard-coded credentials, The client required me to avoid this?

where should I put these setting?

Comment: if thats the case, then create a config file

Comment: If the client does not want hardcoded credentials, how does he want to have them entered? Does he want to edit them? Or have them put in via a web form interactively each time and store them in a cookie at the client's browser?

Comment: I would suggest and ini or xml configuration file, if it needs to be edited by hand, or serialized json file if handled programatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `config` file:

```
require_once("../path-to-your-config/config.php");
```

Example usage:

```
require_once("../path-to-your-config/config.php");

class ABC {

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->mysqli = new \mysqli(Conf::HOST, Conf::USER, Conf::PASSWORD, Conf::DB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @user1978142 said, a config file would be best for storing this kind of information. Preferably this config file should be stored outside the server directory (so no one can accidentally get external access). Moreover, you should ensure that access to this file is restricted to select users

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate file called `credentials.php` and put it in a folder which not the `root` folder or restrict access to the folder and the file inside of it. In this file, assign all the values you want `$server`, `$username`, `$password` etc. and whenever you need them, just use the `require_once` function so that you can get access to them.

You can also consider using `PDO` if it's a matter of changing from one database to another.

Comment: Name the file .credentials.php - most apache servers don't serve files beginning with a dot, which adds a little bit to safety. And make it readable only to the daemon user account under which the server process runs.

Comment: @AlexMonthy the question I always ask when hear such a superstition: surely you always follow this advise yourself, aren't you?

Comment: @YCS: It depends. On work for clients which I do not supervise afterwards, yes I do. For my own purposes, no. But then I'm only responsible to myself.

Comment: How can PDO help with avoiding hardcoding credentials?