# Is there a safe way to store database credentials used in code when working with a public repository?

Tags: mysql, encryption, passwords, repository, credentials

Say I have the mysql credentials

> username: mysqlusername
>
> password: letmein

In my code somewhere, I'm going to have to establish a connection to my database using these credentials.

However, if I'm using a public repository (e.g. github), I don't want to have a line of code that says

```
mysql_connect("localhost","mysqlusername","letmein","my_db");
```

because then anybody could see these credentials.

What is the best way to hide these credentials, while still having all my code in a public repository?

Comment: This is not so much on mysql or repositories but rather about the programming language/environment you are using. I suppose it is python? Generally, you can ask the creds interactively from the user or set it as runtime argument when launching the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)

Comment: Store the credentials in O/S environment variables.