# Android - Better way to maintain DB User Name and Password while DB calls

Tags: php, android, mysql, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm new to `Android`. I'm developing and `Android app` which contains some `database` calls. I'm sending `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD` as parameters in `POST` request to `PHP` and then get `MYSQL Database connection` using `PHP`.

Is it good to pass `Database` `User Name` and `Password` as Parameters ?

or

Should we give `Database` `User Name` and `Password` in `PHP` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't send the DB username, password as parameters. Have them in the PHP.

Comment: Will be there any Security Issue, if we have DB User Name and Password in PHP File ?

Comment: You can store the credentials in a file not web accessible, then include that file in your PHP project. Without the include you could potentially expose the username/password if the PHP is served as plain text for some reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By asking this kind of question i highly recommend you to first read into the basics of web-security!! :)

**Sending credential´s over the web to your server for it to access a database is an absolut no-go.**

- Your webserver stores the credential´s in a seperate file which is not accessible through the web. You can do that by having the credential-file outside of the document-root of your webserver.
- **Furthermore**: Your DB-Server should only accept communication from trusted IP`s. If youre web-app instance and DB-instance are on the same server, only accept from localhost.

---

You probably want to authenticate youre app-clients for limiting the accessibility of your database calls. Commonly you send the client`s credential`s once, which the server validates and responds with an auth-token. For any further communication the token is used, which invalidates after defined period of time. (Token-Based Authentication)

The idea is to minimize the exposed time frame of the credential`s. Even if you use SSL encryption for.

Best of luck
Hannes