# Secure mysql configuration file in vps having multiple developers granted root users

Tags: php, mysql, security, config

Referencing this question: [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97984/6826238)

In Dedicated or VPS server, How to secure mysql configuration file that contains DB username & password. Which can be used in php applications.

Having multiple root users on that server.

How to best secure config.php from local users and hackers?

Comment: Mutil=Multi.
Sorry for typo

Comment: You can fix your own typos by using the [edit] button.

Comment: You can make it more hard for hackers by disallow to show this file via `.htaccess`. So it's more safe from outside and you can include the file into your php files.