# Securing PHP functions and Important files

Tags: php, mysql

Based on the answer at [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php), php file with sensitive content should be move out of the source code. Where in the server should I put them?

I have a php file that I put outside the `www`folder in wamp and accessing them using an absolute path `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\config\sql.php`. In my php file, when I try to use mySQL, I will include the file using:

```
<?php 
  include 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\config\sql.php'; 
?>
```

Is that secure? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: i think as long as this is out of your public_html folder on the live server, you should be good.

Comment: Most of php frameworks uses project/public/ for remote acces files such as index.php, css, js, img, ... and project/private/ for the application config, controllers, models, views, ... You don't have to get those files out of www/ directory.