# What are the advantages of storing info on .env files as opposed to .php files?

Tags: php

Considering storing settings information on a .env file, outside the document root folder, as the best practices suggest... What would be the advantages of using .env files as opposed to .php files?

.env files would be parsed by a library and stored on ENV variables.
.php files don't need parsing and will store info on ENV variables.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen There are nice comments there.
I believe there is no difference in the file extension used (php or env file) to store the settings, but was looking for other views. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When developing you will have a set of keys that you configure on your local environment or whichever other enviroment you are developing. These keys (password to databases, email services, etc) you do not wish to share with other developers that work along side you. Neither if you are sharing the code with the world.

`.env` files where created in order for you to have a working environment without having to share those keys with the world or the rest of your team. They are supposed to be singular to the environment the project is settled.

When you create keys that are going to be used across the project, besides of adding them to your `.env` file you also should add them to the `.env.example` which is pushed to the repository. Leave the keys present in there while keeping the values empty for the `.env.example` so other developers understand what are the required keys for the project to work and what they should add in there while not giving a hint of what your local passwords are.

Also when you are working on local environments you normally use local passwords. A problem arises when you are deploying to a production server where real passwords that contain sensitive information will exist. So you do not want these to exist on your repository and definitely you do not desire these to be permanently stored in your repository (this comes with profession responsibility, specially when you are tagged just as a developer and not a sys admin, in the case where the sysadmin will add the keys once the project is deployed on the production environment).

It is a elegant way to bypass these problems above

**In response to your second question in the comments**

To be honest you can do it both ways if you end up following what I explained above. The main goal is to keep your variables protected. But you can just refuse to push the php file to repo.

In my opinion on why you should use `.env` instead of `.php` goes as follow:
1. with `.env` you immediately know it is a environment variable holder. `.php` regardless of how you name it is not as direct in understanding;
2. `.env` will be an ocult file when listing a directory;
3. It is easier, when working whit other developers in the same repo, to quickly identify and understand something should not be pushed on that commit (think even on the case of adding extra layer of security on a hook to make sure `.env` is not pushed on the commit. It is harder and you have to hardcode this for `.php` files);

I guess in your argument level these will be a few of the Go Tos when deciding between files. I would leave the `.php` files to be precisely that, `php programming files instead of configs`;

Now if you ask me between `.env` or `.yml` etc, I would say go with the one you are familiar/feel comfortable. At the end you avoided the `.php` the same :)

**PS**: Also, if you think on how you will reference them within the code whenever you need one of the `environment variables` it jumps way quicker to the eye when you see something like:

```
getenv('YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your point, still, my question is, you recommend using .env files which don't get pushed to the repo. What's the advantage of using a .env file vs using a .php file (in exactly the same way, but using PHP language in the file)

Answer (score 2):

.env files were created to make development more easy, and is not only used in PHP, as example in ruby you can use .env files https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv.

If we take a look at the twelve factor principles. The following is stated:

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables (often shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.

https://12factor.net/config

So dotenv is just a tool to make this easy for the developers

Comment: Ok, so if your cautios about what to check-in the repo and you don't care about language inter-operability, there should be no difference, for example in terms of security?

Comment: Well, actually It's known that code like `phpinfo()` can expose the environment variables. Some see this as extra security risk, my opinion is that this is a mistake of the developer and should never end up in the code base.