# Config.ini is the best place to store database credentials

Tags: php

my question is that the in PHP language config.ini file is the best place to store database credentials?

I have used config.php file so for to store my database credentials.

```
<?php 
$config = [
    // Database informations
    "database" => [
        "databaseName" => "learning",
        "userName"     => "root",
        "host"         => "localhost",
        "password"     => ""
    ]
```

Comment: No, its not. The best place is in a hidden env file. The vlucas/phpdotenv is a great for this. You can use this as a reference on how to do this: komalbarun/gohybrid

Answer (score 1):

It`s good, but not the best.
You must to put your database(or other security configs) to .env or .ini file and hide it.
for example move file to **outside of the web root**, so that you can be sure no one can access the file by navigating directly to it.

And I suggest to read [how to secure database passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)

More importantly things you should know is never show or access to change config file with php or other editors, just edit it directly.

Comment: Thanks, ttrasn got it.

Comment: @shakilkhan your welcome, please accept this answer