# How can I ensure security for the PHP Web Rest API?

Tags: php

I am creating simple CRUD operations and Pack APIs on MySQL to use in my mobile application. However, I don't know how to provide security here. I want my database connection information not to be taken and malicious users to not be able to access it. For example, in the code below, the deletion process is carried out according to the user ID information received from the users table via the POST method.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'database_name';
$username = 'database_username';
$password = 'database_password';

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

$userID = intval($_POST["user_id"]);

$response = array();

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = :userID");
    $stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userID);
    $stmt->execute();

    $response['status'] = "success";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $response['status'] = "error";
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: So you have a web server out there that can receive a POST from anywhere on the internet, right? How is that endpoint secured? Do users have to sign in in some fashion, or provide something private, like a token, to identify themselves?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hello, no login required. I just make a simple request to the URL where the API is located in my Android application with HTTP libraries like Volley or Retrofit. It's actually very simple

Comment: The database connection information is irrelevant. With your current design, the endpoints themselves are unsecured, so anybody can hit them and delete records without ever knowing the database connection information. You need to wrap this endpoint with an explicit authentication check. There are many ways to do that but the implementation details are beyond the scope of a question here.

Comment: The concepts you need here are "authentication" (proving who the user making the request is) and "authorisation" (deciding what actions that authenticated user is allowed to do, and which data records they're allowed to do them to). You need to implement those in your app, so that you don't have a situation where anyone can send a request to your URL and delete any record they like. If you're writing an API, a common way to provide authentication is using an OAuth2-compatible system. There are no doubt libraries/plugins you can use to get a solution up and running pretty fast. Don't DIY!

Comment: P.S. In terms of the database username and password themselves, nobody can steal those unless the server is badly misconfigured. They are within the PHP code, so when someone makes a request to the API, the PHP is executed, and the _output_ of that execution is returned to the caller. The actual code itself is never sent to the client-side - **unless** the server isn't set up to execute PHP code. That should be a "never" event really, on a properly managed system. If you're very concerned though, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

Comment: @ADyson Hello, first of all, database connection information is unimportant, there is no need to think about it, I understand. How can I configure OAuth2? As you can see, I want to perform CRUD operations by accessing my MySQL database from my mobile application in a very simple way. I want to do it with PHP (or I don't know what else it could be) with a simple URL directly without running any Node. Is there a tutorial getting started?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+oauth2

Comment: Or if you requirement is much simpler you could consider a cruder system such as the Basic Auth mentioned in the answer below. But in that scenario you have to consider that the credentials would need to be stored in the mobile app, and that in itself is a security risk. Is this API simply for yourself, or is the intention that many people will use it? It wasn't clear?

Comment: If the client side app already requires the user to login, then you can just piggyback the API hits on the user's session.

Comment: @ADyson I did some research. I asked chatgpt but these are too complex situations for my example.. I want something simpler. I just want to connect to mysql securely and perform CRUD operations. I want to build a structure like my example, but safer. Direct transactions can be made... but no malicious person can reach here. because these urls can be found publicly and users can be deleted.. domain.com/api/delete_user.php?user_id=5

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is it only _you_ who's supposed to be accessing this API, or lots of people?

Comment: too many people will access it. In other words, transactions will be constantly made in MySQL within the mobile application. Users will perform operations such as user registration, adding posts, deleting posts and deleting users. You can think of it like a social media application. @ADyson

Comment: In that case you _definitely_ need a more complex system such as OAuth. If the user logs into the mobile app with their credentials then the access token from that can then be used for the API calls. The API (or a federated service that you integrate, such as Google or Facebook Login) should be handling the logins too in any case. That way, the API can identify the individual user who is sending the request to the API and ensure that they are not only a valid user, but they have permission to perform the specific action / update the specific record.

Comment: For example you don't want users deleting each other's posts, etc. So therefore the API must be able to identify who is sending the request. Simple Basic Auth can't help you with that.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about the web side, so where can I create the simplest, most accurate and most reliable API for me? Should I do it again with PHP or ASPNET Core, or Python, NodeJS... Whichever would be easier? Frankly, I don't want to run it manually. For example, I used socket io for node js, but for this it is necessary to run it as node app.js in the SSH terminal. What is your suggestion for me? @ADyson

Comment: How protective would doing such a simple thing be?

 `
$api_key = "your_api_key";

if(isset($_POST['api_key']) && $_POST['api_key'] == $api_key) {
// database operation
}
`

Comment: It would be OK, except that a) the API key would need to be stored in the mobile app, so there's a chance someone could obtain it through that, and b) it doesn't let you identify individual users, so there's no way to enforce authorisation of specific actions or specific data items, as I mentioned earlier

Comment: `I don't have any knowledge about the web side`...well if you're planning to implement a complex multi-user system like the one you've described then you'll need to learn pretty fast! Sounds like you have bitten off way more than you can chew at this stage. Practice doing some server side programming first. And consider using a framework which can help you build an API the right way - there are a few free ones available for php if you search, and for the other languages you mentioned

Comment: During this time, as a result of chatgpt and my research, I thought it was right to learn ASPNET Web API and started to receive some training on both RESTful and ASP CORE. But this seems very complicated to me. Most importantly, it needs to be operated manually. I can create a node js application on my server with the Plesk panel, but it needs to be run manually, like node app.js. Do you think PHP would make more sense at this stage? @ADyson